# Java add more than one JPanel objects into JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I am a beginer and I dont know how to add more objects into JFrame.
How could I add more than one JPanel objects into JFrame?
Below is what I have tried.

Thanks for your help.

```
public class Init extends JFrame{

    public Init(){
        super("Ball");

        Buttons t = new Buttons();

        JumpingBall b1 = new JumpingBall();
        JumpingBall b2 = new JumpingBall();

        t.addBall(b1);
        t.addBall(b2);

        add(b1);
        add(b2);


        setSize(500,500);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use Layouts. Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `JumpingBall` extends `JPanel`, you might want to have a look at the java layout managers here: [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

The default `Layout` for a `JFrame` is the `BorderLayout` and if you didn't specify where you want to add your component, The `BorderLayout` will put it in the center by default. In `BorderLayout`, you cannot have more that one component in the same area. So, in your example you will end up having only the second `JumpingBall` panel in your frame. If you want to have more than one component at the center, then you will have to create a `JPanel` and add those components to it using different Layout. The common three Layouts are the `BorderLayout`, `FlowLayout` and `GridLayout` Please have a look at the provided link above to see how the components are arranged.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a number of `JPanel` objects in a `JFrame`, using the `add` method. If only one is displayed, you might need to change your Layout options or use a Layout Manager (Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more).

Comment: Ok, nice to hear. Do not forget to vote as best whatever answer you think it answers your question more completely.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing only one because it overlapping each other. Just provide `setbound(x,y,x1,y1)` for you panel component and you will see your panel at location.

or use `setLayout(new FlowLayout());` which is going to order your component in respective to other so you will not override each-other.